# Finding out the scale when using MinMaxScaler()

Tags: feature-scaling

I am using the MinMaxScaler() of sklearn to scale my features before using kmeans.I needed to find the scale used.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler= scaler.fit_transform(finance_features)
print scaler.scale_
```

However on using the line

```
print scaler.scale_
```

It shows an error saying no such attribute

Comment: Working for me. Using python 3.5 installed with anaconda.

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you were importing a class as name 'scalar' and modifying it by assigning value obtained after transforming. Just change

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(finance_features)
print scaler.scale_
```

This should work.